# Error 512:Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a requirement where I have to build the dynamic sql, one of the input parameter is varchar(max) that contains the integer values which I need to validate against the bigint column.

```
SELECT @query = 'select file-id,file-Name from Files '
SELECT @Clause = 'where'
SELECT @colName = 'file-id'
SELECT @Filter = '1,2,3,4'

SELECT @sql = @query + ' ' + @Clause + ' ' + @ColName + ' IN ' + Convert(bigint,(SELECT   csvvalues from [dbo].[SplitString](@Filter,',') as s))
```

when I execute this via execute sp_executesql it is throwing this error.

returnsError#:512|ErrorSubquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

What I'm doing wrong here.Please Help.

Comment: `select csvvalues` is returning more than one row/field of data. you're using it in a context where only one row/value can be returned.

Comment: I don't see the point of `Convert(bigint,(SELECT   csvvalues from [dbo].[SplitString](@Filter,',') as s))` as you appear to be using a CSV ('1,2,3,4') to populate a table, when the `IN` clause could just take your CSV seeing as you are using dynamic SQL. e.g. `SELECT @sql = @query + ' ' + @Clause + ' ' + @ColName + ' IN (' + @Filter + ')'`

Answer (score 4):

The [`IN`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) clause can be used with csv's or tables. As you are calling `SP_EXECUTESQL` you just need a string to determine the filter, hence the following should work: `

```
SELECT @query = 'SELECT file-id,file-Name FROM Files '
SELECT @Clause = 'WHERE'
SELECT @colName = 'file-id'
SELECT @Filter = '1,2,3,4'

SELECT @sql = @query + ' ' + @Clause + ' ' + @ColName + ' IN (' + @Filter + ')'
```